# Need dynamic variables from API before loading AngularJS library

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading

We are developing our application to a multi-tenant environment. Because we are integrating into Auth0 for each client they have their own ApplicationID, callbackUrl etc.

```
angular
    .module('myModule')
    .constant('auth0Config', {
        domain: 'mydomain.io', //needs to be dynamic
        clientId: 'eENGM6UrasdfasdOXMKnJ', //needs to be dynamic
        callbackUrl: window.location.origin
    }
    ...
```

I have an endpoint that accepts `window.location.origin` and will give me the values for the variables that are specific to each URL.

Is there a way to make angularjs load after I make the call do the endpoint to get the specific variables that I need?

Comment: How does your application decide which tenant it is? If nothing you can have a simple JSON API which returns public client id's depending on the domain using `location.origin`.

Comment: the tenant is determined by the URL. The problem with that approach is that we'd have to maintain that JSON for every server that our applications are on.

Comment: Maybe a better way would be to configure the server to recognize the tenant and send the appropriate information to the Angular page.  Then your code could find the information in the query string of the URL.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, I'd like to avoid a server side solution